# How to give user inside specific role accessibility to all activity except from user with the same role

Tags: tasks, activities, sharing-rule, sharing-sets, restrictionrules

I need to give a user accessibility to all activity except activity that own by other user in the same role
[image]
What I want is user inside **CFO** role can see all activity except activity that own from other user inside **CFO role**
I already using Restriction rule but now user with **CFO role** can't see Activity that assign to them.

The condition right now:

| User | Role | Task | User A Can See The Task |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | CFO | Task A | **False** (Can't see their own Task) |
| B | CEO | Task B | True |
| C | CFO | Task C | False |

Here what I expect:

| User | Role | Task | User A Can See The Task |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | CFO | Task A | True |
| B | CEO | Task B | True |
| C | CFO | Task C | False |

Anyone can help, please?

Thanks in advance